# Chrome extension popup not showing?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

Well this is not showing the popup help!!!! When I run it the extension looks a bit white, without colour and when i click it the popup doesn't show up. Honestly I haven't got a clue!

```
 {
      "name": "Youtube",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "description": "Youtube",
      "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
      },
      "default_locale": "en",
      "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon19.png",
        "default_title": "page action demo",
        "default_popup": "files/popup.html"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "bookmarks",
        "chrome://favicon/",
        "clipboardRead",
        "clipboardWrite",
        "contentSettings",
        "contextMenus",
        "cookies",
        "fileBrowserHandler",
        "tts",
        "ttsEngine",
        "history",
        "idle",
        "management",
        "notifications",
        "tabs",
        "geolocation"
      ],
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "http://www.youtube.com*"
          ],
          "js": [
            "js/Youtube.js"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page action needs to be "shown" for the button to do anything, i.e. you have to either call `chrome.pageAction.show` for a tab or use `chrome.declarativeContent` to show it.

Blame Google for crippling Page Actions so they are now unintuitive.

If you want an always-active button you need a Browser Action instead.